# One Page User Profile

Tags: commerce

How do I make a one-page user profile? I want to include wishlist, cardonfile and addressbook from commerce, and render all the data already inserted into the profile, and edit/create forms on the individual user page.

Thanks!

Comment: What options have you already tried to pursue?

Comment: I have tried rendering the forms with drupal_get_form, but it didn't work at all...

Answer (score 0):

To keep this convo going even though I do not have a definitive answer...

I feel that is a pretty big question with a fair bit of config and templating even... So my short answer would be Views and/or Blocks. Depending on your needs maybe you could do just a views page with filters and relationships as you need populated with commerce entities and content types. Maybe you need views blocks, blocks, and content types with template files to render everything on the same page. My gut just tells me that's the pace to start. Views is Drupal cores way of bringing many things together.